# Provider for jakarta.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder cannot be found

Tags: java, rest-client

I am trying to build a `RESTful` client with `jakarta 10.0.0`

`ClientBuilder.newClient()` is failing with this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Provider for jakarta.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder cannot be found
```

A Provider is not found. What could be the problem?
How can I fix that?
I have added the `jakarta 10.0.0` dependency to the maven project pom file. What else do I have to add?

```
package com.tbs.companyclient;

import jakarta.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import jakarta.ws.rs.client.Client;
import jakarta.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

/**
 *
 * @author tom
 */
public class CompanyWebClient {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create a JAX-RS client
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

    // Define the target endpoint of the RESTful web service
    WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8080/CompanyWebService/resources/company/departments");

    // Make a GET request to the target endpoint and specify the expected response media type
    String response = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class);

    // Print the response
    System.out.println("Response:");
    System.out.println(response);

    // Close the client
    client.close();
  }
}
```

This is the pom file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.tbs</groupId>
    <artifactId>CompanyClient</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>22</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>22</maven.compiler.target>
        <exec.mainClass>com.tbs.companyclient.CompanyClient</exec.mainClass>
    </properties>
    <description>RESTful Client for the CompanyWebService</description>
    <name>CompanyWebClient</name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Compiling works, when trying to run the app the described error occurs.

Comment: Post your POM file.

Comment: I have added the pom file.

Answer (score 3):

Jakarta is a specification and the dependency you have contains only the specification not the implementation.

An implementation for the specification is required in the runtime and `jersey` is one such implementation and it can be used in the runtime.

[Jersey 3.1.5](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey/download.html) provides implementation for [Jakarta RESTful WebServices 3.1.0](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/restful-ws/3.1/)(Released for Jakarta EE 10)

Add following dependency to resolve the problem.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Always this newbie problems.

Comment: If deploying to a Jakarta-compliant app server, the server will include an implementation if it meets the *Web Profile* or *Full Profile* of Jakarta EE standard. In this case , add a Maven  [`scope`](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-dependency-scopes) element of `provided` to indicate you need this library at development but do not want it bundled into your final artifact (such as JAR or WAR file).

Comment: If you want to be able to change implementations, be sure your code only calls methods defined in the Jakarta specification, and do not call any methods in the `org.glassfish.jersey` namespace.