while upgrading from keycloak 23 to 25 facing: Failed authentication: ClassNotFoundException: Provider for jakarta.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder
Aug 21 07:34:36 xxxx d01kc\[2326\]: 2024-08-21 07:34:36,129 WARN \[org.keycloak.services\] (executor-thread-2) KC-SERVICES0013: Failed authentication: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Provider for jakarta.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder cannot be found  
Aug 21 07:34:36 xx d01kc\[2326\]: #011at jakarta.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newBuilder(ClientBuilder.java:75)  
Aug 21 07:34:36 xx d01kc\[2326\]: #011at jakarta.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newClient(ClientBuilder.java:86)  
Aug 21 07:34:36 xx d01kc\[2326\]: #011at xx.xx..updateInfo(xxx.java:273)

We tried adding the dependency below.
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.13.2</version>
</dependency>


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78010554/provider-for-jakarta-ws-rs-client-clientbuilder-cannot-be-found might help

Does your xxx.java belong to your custom Keycloak provider JAR or you are customizing Keycloak source code with your own code?

You can try to use this dependencys:
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-rest</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
   <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client-jackson</artifactId>
</dependency>

